# How to publish wsdl in to UDDI?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Can any one tell me how to publish the web service(which is created in java using eclipse) in to the UDDI.Can any one explain me with steps.

thanks for your precious time!...

Answer (score 0):

jUDDI has a number of examples for doing this either programmatically or via annotations.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/

Unfortunately, Eclipse's plugins (currently) are using a very old version of UDDI v2. There's an open ticket on updating here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307202